# BootStrap DropDown on <a> tag without text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to add some dropdown menus to my website. My navigation bar is made up of anchor tags with background-images applied through CSS. The Bootstrap dropdown menu does not seem to work in this scenario. The only way I could get it to work was to add text between the anchor tag, in which case the text would trigger the dropdown but not the anchor tags background image as one would expect through normal CSS :hover pseudo classes.

An example of my html:

```
<a class="logo_master" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"></a>
```

My CSS:

```
.logo_master
{
    display:block;
    background-image:url(../images/logo_master.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:169px;
    height:39px;
}
```

I was also able to get it to work by adding an img between the anchor tags but I am using a sprite that was previously setup and I want to avoid having to creat all new images and adding them inline.

Answer (score 0):

use `<i>` tag for your sprite images:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"><i class="logo_master" /></a>
```